# How to get USER input from html and search for it in databse with Python

Tags: python, html, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a database and i want to search in it with this HTML

```
       <form action="/question/search" method="POST">
           <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
           <button id="search" type="submit">&#x1F50D;</button>
      </form>
```

I get the data in my function

```
@app.route("/question/search",methods=["POST"])
def search():
    search_result = request.form.get("search")
    story = data_handler.get_search_result(search_result)
    return render_template('search_resoult.html', stories=story)
```

but i just cant figure out the SQl for it i tried :

```
@database_common.connection_handler
def get_search_result(cursor,item):
    my_sql = "SELECT * FROM question WHERE title LIKE %s OR message LIKE %s"
    my_resoult = (item)
    cursor.execute(my_sql, my_resoult)
    resoult = cursor.fetchall()
    return resoult
```

I just want to all the data that has my_result in the title or in the message.
It always gives me this error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your query requires 2 values to be unpacked, but you're only giving a single one `(item)`. If you want to use `item` as the condition for both `title LIKE` and `message LIKE`, you should expand `my_resoult`:

```py
my_resoult = (item, item)
```